# I have a figure showing that on different datasets, method 1 is x times faster than method 2. What is a good x axis label?

Tags: publications

I have many datasets(over 10000), and two data processing methods A and B. B takes only 1/2 to 1/5 time of A to run on them. I want to draw a graph showing on these datasets, how much B is faster than A.

I use the ratio of their running time.
E.g., on Set 1, A uses `30 sec`, B uses `5 sec`, and the ratio is `6x`. On Set 2, A uses `180 sec`, B uses `50 sec`, the ratio is `3.6x`.

Now I draw a distribution bar graph. [image]The X axis is the ratio described above, the Y axis is the percentage of datasets with that ratio. So assume there is a bar at `(X,Y)` in the figure, it means "There are Y% datasets on which A takes X times compared to B".

What is a good X label for this kind of graph? Do I just write "Ratio of Running Time Between A and B"?

Comment: What do the x-axis values mean? What are the differences between the sets?

Comment: @Michelle No difference. Each dataset is just a sample. The X-axis is the running speed of Method A over running speed of Method B. As I mentioned, if on a sample, A use a sec to run, B use b sec to run. The X-axis for that sample is a/b.

Comment: The confusion is in your description. "Set" makes it sound like there are differences in the nature of the datasets - e.g. different number of rows, different number of columns, different mixes of variable types. "Sample" has a specific technical statistical meaning, where the number of things sampled is mentioned. Depending on what you mean by these terms, a single graph containing all results may or may not be a good representation of your results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several possibilities. The one you suggested is OKish, but I'd prefer a shorter form like

> Running time ratio A/B

Another possibility is to denote by *t*(A) and *t*(B) the running times of the two data processing methods and label the axis as

> *t*(A)/*t*(B)

Finally let me point out that the unit symbol for second is "s" not "sec" [[SI Brochure](https://www.bipm.org/en/publications/si-brochure/)], and that a ratio is just 6, 3.6 etc. without appending any multiplication symbol.